# In $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, using Fourier coefficients calculate the spectrum of the right-shift operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> In $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, what is the spectrum of the right-shift operator?

I have looked at relevant posts on the website and noticed that someone had mentioned in hints that $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and hence the right-shift operator can be transformed into a multiplication operator. I am interested in this approach and could anyone show how this is achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is **isometric** to $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ through the Fourier's transform, namely the following map is an isometry:
$$f\mapsto\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)e^{-int}\mathrm{d}t\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}.$$
This is partially a consequence of Parseval's equality.

Now, notice that the right-shift operator in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ becomes the multiplication by $x\mapsto e^{-ix}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ through the above isometry. Therefore, since $\mathbb{S}^1=\{e^{it},t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, the spectrum of the multiplication by $x\mapsto e^{-ix}$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$ and so is the spectrum of the right-shift operator.

I let you work out why the spectrum is unchanged through the isometry.

Comment: How do you determine that the spectrum of the multiplication operator is $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: This is the continuous spectrum (the point spectrum is empty). We can see it in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ by saying that $e^{it}$ is an approximate eigenvalue of the sequence of sequences $x_k(n)= e^{int}e^{-n^2/k^2}$ @userHasNoNumber

Comment: I have trouble seeing that $M-e^{it} I$ is not invertible. Could you please tell me why it is not invertible?

Comment: It is not **boundedly** invertible (not invertible in the set of bounded operators)

Comment: @user1952009 got it!

Comment: @C.Falcon What you said about a nonzero vector in the kernel of $M-\lambda Id$ is unclear (we have a distribution $\delta(x-t)$ in the kernel)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that is why I delete my comment about it. That was totally misleading! Thank you for clarifying the situation!